# How to group and merge JSON objects composed of a couple of objects?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON response which contains several objects composed of a couple of objects (datacenter, environment) :

```
"deployments": [
                    {
                        "datacenter": {
                            "title": "euw1",
                            "name": "foodatacenter",
                            "revision": "0",
                            "state": "Active"
                        },
                        "environment": {
                            "clusterId": "AAA",
                            "name": "foocluster",
                            "revision": "0",
                            "state": "Active",

                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "datacenter": {
                            "title": "apc1",
                            "name": "foodatacenter",
                            "revision": "0",
                            "state": "Active"
                        },
                        "environment": {
                            "clusterId": "BBB",
                            "name": "foocluster",
                            "revision": "0",
                            "state": "Active"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "datacenter": {
                            "title": "euw1",
                            "name": "foodatacenter",
                            "revision": "0",
                            "state": "Active"
                        },
                        "environment": {
                            "clusterId": "BBB",
                            "name": "foocluster",
                            "revision": "0",
                            "state": "Active"
                        }
                    },
                     {
                        "datacenter": {
                            "title": "use1",
                            "name": "foodatacenter",
                            "revision": "0",
                            "state": "Active"
                        },
                        "environment": {
                            "clusterId": "AAA",
                            "name": "foocluster",
                            "revision": "0",
                            "state": "Active"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "datacenter": {
                            "title": "use2",
                            "name": "foodatacenter",
                            "revision": "0",
                            "state": "Active"
                        },
                        "environment": {
                            "clusterId": "AAA",
                            "name": "foocluster",
                            "revision": "0",
                            "state": "Active"
                        }
                    },
    ]
```

What is the best way to group by environment using javascript? The desired JSON result is as follows :

```
"deployments": [
                    {
                            "clusterId": "AAA",
                            "name": "foocluster",
                            "revision": "0",
                            "state": "Active",
                            "datacenters":[
                               {
                                 "title": "euw1",
                                 "name": "foodatacenter",
                                 "revision": "0",
                                 "state": "Active"
                               },
                               {
                                 "title": "use1",
                                 "name": "foodatacenter",
                                 "revision": "0",
                                 "state": "Active"
                               },
                               {
                                 "title": "use2",
                                 "name": "foodatacenter",
                                 "revision": "0",
                                 "state": "Active"
                               },
                           ]
                    },
                    {
                            "clusterId": "BBB",
                            "name": "foocluster",
                            "revision": "0",
                            "state": "Active",
                            "datacenters":[
                               {
                                 "title": "euw1",
                                 "name": "foodatacenter",
                                 "revision": "0",
                                 "state": "Active"
                               },
                               {
                                 "title": "apc1",
                                 "name": "foodatacenter",
                                 "revision": "0",
                                 "state": "Active"
                               }
                           ]
                    }

    ]
```

Your help would be so appreciated.
Thank you so much!

Comment: you just have to loop the data and find what you need, then write it out again. There's no magic special sauce, or SQL-like syntax or anything to find stuff. Have you done anything so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: @Liam no comment, check this https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Comment: Well you're not a new user. I also pretty much disagree with most of what that link says ([and I'm not the only one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366875/policing-in-the-aftermath-of-the-blog-post-of-welcomingness)). If you want my help put some effort in yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to group the data based on `environment` `clusterId` in an object and add all the `datacenter` corresponding to similar `clusterId` and then extract the values from the object.

```js
const data = {"deployments": [ { "datacenter": { "title": "euw1", "name": "foodatacenter", "revision": "0", "state": "Active" }, "environment": { "clusterId": "AAA", "name": "foocluster", "revision": "0", "state": "Active", } }, { "datacenter": { "title": "apc1", "name":"foodatacenter", "revision": "0", "state": "Active" }, "environment": { "clusterId": "BBB", "name": "foocluster", "revision": "0", "state": "Active" } }, { "datacenter": { "title": "euw1", "name": "foodatacenter", "revision": "0", "state": "Active" },"environment": { "clusterId": "BBB", "name": "foocluster", "revision": "0", "state": "Active" } }, { "datacenter": { "title": "use1", "name": "foodatacenter", "revision": "0", "state": "Active" }, "environment": { "clusterId": "AAA", "name": "foocluster","revision": "0", "state": "Active" } }, { "datacenter": { "title": "use2", "name": "foodatacenter", "revision": "0", "state": "Active" }, "environment": { "clusterId": "AAA", "name": "foocluster", "revision": "0", "state": "Active" } }]},
    result = Object.values(data.deployments.reduce((r,{datacenter, environment}) => {
      const key = environment.clusterId;
      r[key] = r[key] || {...environment, datacenters : []};
      r[key].datacenters.push({...datacenter});
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```

```js
"use strict";

var _extends = Object.assign || function (target) { for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) { var source = arguments[i]; for (var key in source) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) { target[key] = source[key]; } } } return target; };

var data = { "deployments": [{ "datacenter": { "title": "euw1", "name": "foodatacenter", "revision": "0", "state": "Active" }, "environment": { "clusterId": "AAA", "name": "foocluster", "revision": "0", "state": "Active" } }, { "datacenter": { "title": "apc1", "name": "foodatacenter", "revision": "0", "state": "Active" }, "environment": { "clusterId": "BBB", "name": "foocluster", "revision": "0", "state": "Active" } }, { "datacenter": { "title": "euw1", "name": "foodatacenter", "revision": "0", "state": "Active" }, "environment": { "clusterId": "BBB", "name": "foocluster", "revision": "0", "state": "Active" } }, { "datacenter": { "title": "use1", "name": "foodatacenter", "revision": "0", "state": "Active" }, "environment": { "clusterId": "AAA", "name": "foocluster", "revision": "0", "state": "Active" } }, { "datacenter": { "title": "use2", "name": "foodatacenter", "revision": "0", "state": "Active" }, "environment": { "clusterId": "AAA", "name": "foocluster", "revision": "0", "state": "Active" } }] },
    result = Object.values(data.deployments.reduce(function (r, o) {
  var datacenter = o.datacenter,
      environment = o.environment;

  var key = environment.clusterId;
  r[key] = r[key] || _extends({}, environment, { datacenters: [] });
  r[key].datacenters.push(_extends({}, datacenter));
  return r;
}, {}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hello @Hassan Imam i'm facing errors when using YUI Compressor with this code. For example it doesn't like passing an object to reduce anonymous function {datacenter, environment}, also to errors in line 4 and 5 . How can i write the same code to be correctly compressed http://refresh-sf.com/ ? Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @Obama, I have added ES5 solution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any option other than looping on the array and collecting `datacenter` objects by `environment`. In pseudo-code, this will be:

1. for each object in the array

   1. key = JSON.stringify(o.environment);
   2. find key in a dictionary.
   3. if key is not found, add it, and add an array as value
   4. add `datacenter` to the array for key
2. create a result array
3. for each item in dictionary

   1. create an `environment` from the key
   2. create an item in the result, with the fields from the `environment` and the `datacenter` objects in the value.